# Maintaining POST data between Twilio interactions

Tags: c#, twilio, mv

I am wondering hows best to maintain information collected from Twilio interactions.

Say I am collecting a PIN in stage one. Then a FAX number in stage two.

Can I tell Twilio to POST the validated data back to my app on the next request? So when asking for FAX, PIN is also posted and parsed.

Failing that I could use a session, or send the info back in the querystring/GET.

Would be great to hear how others have handled this.

N.B. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566096/twilio-to-post-gather-digits-with-other-details) that supports the idea of using GET. However, I would want to try and avoid this method if possible.

Comment: two general sentences. 1. REST webserwices are stateles. 2. In short, in REST: POST==insert, PUT==update (I don't know twilio, assume is correct designed)

Comment: thanks am aware of that. I'm wondering if I could tell twilio to include some data in the TwiML response. Failing that I will go with sessions or GET. Hence my question on what is best suited/possible. Twilio also serves cookies with the requests.
As for the close flag, I'm looking for; "facts, references, or specific expertise."!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't directly tell Twilio to keep your application's state and send it as part of subsequent POST requests.

You do mention some alternatives, such as using the cookies that Twilio supports to keep data or appending data to the query string of the next URL.

I think personally I'd feel safest if I was storing the data on my side. I would collect the data you need from the call against the `CallSid` in a database of some sort and once you have collected all the data that you need, enter it to your database against the record that you are creating. This way you are always storing the data you receive, you can use partially complete calls to discover if there is a particular drop off stage, and even create new calls to complete the data collection rather than starting from scratch with a caller each time they make an attempt.

These are all just options though and your own application architecture should inform your choice as to which is best.

Comment: Great answer, many thanks phil! Some really good benefits over inproc or similar. Cheers!

Comment: No worries, hope your app is going well!